# Authenticate to Gsuite APIs without service account

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, gcloud, google-workspace

I'm trying to read Google Spreadsheet using my local credentials (i.e. not service account). I'm basically doing:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

service = build('sheets', 'v4')
request = sheet_service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range='{}!A1:a4'.format(SHEET_NAME))
result = request.execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
```

However I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./update_incidents_tracker.py", line 54, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "./update_incidents_tracker.py", line 48, in main
    result = request.execute()
  File "/home/filip/.virtualenvs/monitoring-tools/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/filip/.virtualenvs/monitoring-tools/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 898, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1lTcQ3WknG_2oZvy9O9LEbgAzoykOWaheYSaDkkV21wE/values/Incidents%21A1%3Aa4?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">
```

**I can't find a way to set scopes for my local (gcloud SDK) credentials. How can I set proper scopes?**

For reference for service account based authentication I can simply run:

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(CREDENTIALS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
```

Comment: If you already have downloaded a credentials file, you can just follow [this quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample).

Comment: I don't want to use service account because I'm writing a script that multiple user will be running on their machines. I don't want all of them to go though SA generations, which is cumbersome.

Comment: The quickstart I provided doesn't refer to a Service Account. Each user would be using their own credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Use the default credential explicitally, and set the scope at this time

```
import google.auth

credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=....)
build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
....
```

Full documentation of google-auth [here](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.html)

Comment: I still get an error about insufficient scopes. After reading the code it looks like the scopes are not applied if default credentials are from gcloud SDK. Or am I doing something wrong still?

Comment: Where your code is running? what is your current default credential?

Comment: What scopes are you using? Should be [one of these](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get#authorization-scopes).

Comment: I use https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets, and I'm running it on my laptop. If I call google.auth.default, then it uses my gcloud SDK credentials.

Comment: You can only generate an identity token on an API keys. Generate a service account qui file, perform a `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=key.json` where key.json is  your service account key file, and try again.